# batch installing windows update from a local server?

Tags: automation, windows-update

I work for a small PC repair business and installing Windows updates is one of the most dreadful tasks I have to do. Constantly rebooting, and clicking buttons, it gets tiresome.

I'm sure there's more automated ways to do this, although I don't where to begin looking.
 Ideally I would like to have a local server that automatically downloads new updates as they are released and then be able to batch download and install all the required updates on a clients computer, without having to stay close to click next, reboot or whatever.

Anything close to this would make my job a whole lot easier. So many hours wasted installing windows updates when I could be doing something else.

This is probably a noob question, I don't know much about setting up windows networks. Something like this has probably been used for ages in enterprise environments.

Thanks in advance.

btw, I'm mostly working with XP/Vista/Win7 if that matters.

Comment: I'm guessing these are random PCs and not on a domain, so GPOs would be out of the question?

If not, WSUS w/ GPO could be looked into: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720539(WS.10).aspx

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that you are not allowed to use WSUS on pc's not owned by your company, it breaks the licence agreement.

Comment: mmm good call Sam

Comment: Yea, they're all random PCs from random clients. MS sure don't make it easy to keep things legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [WSUS Offline Update](http://www.wsusoffline.net/). It's will automatically install all important updates and even automate the restarts for you if you want.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like exactly what I'm looking for. I'll give it a go tomorrow.